# How to use groupby clause in Entity Framework and ASP.NET MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an `admission` model class as follows:

```
public class admission
{
    public int AdmissionID {get;set;}
    public DateTime Session {get;set;}
    public string Class {get;set;}
    public DateTime RegDate {get;set;} 
}
```

I want to get the report of admission such that how many students are admitted to school each month in current year.

For example :

```
 Month    No.Of.StudentsAdmitted
---------------------------------
  Jan          20              
  Feb           2
  March        10
  April         5

 and so on....
```

Here is the query that I have tried but could not know what I'm exactly doing :

```
db.admissions
   .Where(d => d.regDateTime.Value.Date.Year == DateTime.Now.Year )
   .GroupBy(d => d.regDateTime.Value.Month)
   .ToList();
```

I also want the month name instead of month value.

In more simple words, I want to count the number of students in each month of the current year...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're basically there.  You have a list of Grouping, so just two steps remain to get what you want:

Convert the int (month code) to the month name:

```
var mo = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(g.Key);
```

For each group, count the number of items in each group

```
g.Count()
```

putting it all together:

```
    var resultset = admissions
        .Where(dd => dd.RegDate.Date.Year == DateTime.Now.Year)
        .GroupBy(ddda => ddda.RegDate.Month)
        .Select(s => new
    {
        month = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(s.Key),
        count = s.Count()
    }).ToList();
```

Edit: In case EF complains, you can always move the ToList() up, then select the new anonymous object:

```
 var resultset = admissions
            .Where(dd => dd.RegDate.Date.Year == DateTime.Now.Year)
            .GroupBy(ddda => ddda.RegDate.Month)
            .ToList()
            .Select(s => new
            {
                month = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(s.Key),
                count = s.Count()
            });
```

Comment: thanks @K_foxer ,its was too simple although i found the solution after a long term.....thanx